# How open photoswipe gallery only with a single button

Tags: jquery, photoswipe

I follow this example until the step 3 :

http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html

Iwould like the gallery is oppening only when i click on the button... i don't understand why each time i refresh the page the gallery is already open in fullscreen.

if i close the gallery the button works fine but the gallery shouldn't appear without a click on first time...

the result in the photoswipe's example is already on the gallery.

How could i fix that ?

thank you,

friendly,
Stéphane.

Comment: how many  openPhotoSwipe; do you have?  -- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNyLmV

Comment: OK NICE thx a lot :)

Comment: @Tasos Maybe you know with this base how put a function in js to get multiple gallery like the first one ?

Comment: no i know nothing about Photoswipe but its just a simple case of repeating the code to initialize it -- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqrOVv?editors=1010 -- there maybe an easier way  so its less code but i need to spend more time on it

Comment: hang on that demo was wrong -- wait a minute

Comment: ok thx u it helps me a lot

Comment: i had rename some stuff -- this one works  -- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grPOYz?editors=0010

Comment: no prob's. it should be ok to repeat the code for each gallery but rename it as i have so its different for each gallery -- however you should read the photoswipe docs as im sure their is an easier way so you dont need to repeat the code much

Comment: i'll take a look on doc but it's a bit difficult for me now, i'm just started to JS. THANK YOU for your time on it :)